# content from database as default for text area in html form

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I would like to know the easiest way to extract the text from a database field and set it as the default text for a text area.

I am planning at the moment to assiign the field to a variable, and then using javascript set it as the default text, but I am unsure of how to do this last part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP code, likely above your HTML:

```
// Database connection calls here...
$row = mysql_fetch_array();
$databaseField = $row["databaseField"];
```

And in your HTML:

```
<textarea name="databaseField" rows="5">
   <?php= $databaseField ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a server-side language, it's not necessary to have the extra javascript step.  You can simply populate the value of the "value" attribute.  Here's an example using PHP:

```
<input type="text" 
  name="phoneNumber" 
  value="<?php print($phone_number_from_database); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to escape your database contents!

```
<textarea id="foo">
  <?php echo htmlspecialchars($databasefield); ?>
</textarea>
```

otherwise you'll get problems with content that includes html-tags like `'foo </textarea>bar baz'`. the `bar baz` would escape your textarea! this could lead to [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) security problems (if you allow user input) or at least broken html. i used to punish fellow students by opening countless new windows with javascript if they forgot to sanitize the entries in their learning-by-doing guestbook apps. windows with images *no sane person evers wants to see*. good times :)

htmlspecialchars turns `<, >, ", &, ...`  into entities (`&lt;, &gt;, &quot;, &amp;, ...`), preventing the content to break free.